# Duplicated logo in wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, css

I have not made any core changes, but this morning whilst doing some W3 validation the logo decided to duplicate randomly and I cannot pin point the error.

See here: http://www.fundingoptions.com

I have reverted the header.php file back to original, yet the issue is still there ? Ive not made any css changes...

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't look like it's css related. The first logo links to contact and the second links to the frontpage (as one would expect).
The css states that an anchor tag inside the h1 should have that image as background. So you probably just have to remove the anchor tag that links to contact page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two entries in your H1 tag, most likely the object is styled with a background image via css against the a tag. Remove one of these and it should be ok.

```
<h1>
<a style="color:#fff" href="/contact-us"></a>
<a href="http://www.fundingoptions.com"></a>
</h1>
```

Comment: Cheers Johannes. Thought that was the case!

Comment: There are two mentions of <h1> inside the header.php file:

Comment: <div class="wrapper type-2">
    <h1<?php if ( ! $use_image_logo) { echo ' class="style-1"'; } ?>><a href="<?php ether::info('url'); ?>"><?php echo ether::option('html_logo_title'); ?></a></h1>

Comment: I cant see all the code, post it up in a JS fiddle. Its a very simple fix.

Comment: Both of those instances are in the header.php file, the top one is at the bottom and vice versa (in the file). I think its dynamically loading the <h1> hence not being able to just remove it ?

Comment: Easy fix, just go into your style.css and remove #header h1 a {
    background: url("../images/rfa-logo.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    display: block;
    height: 53px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 300px !important;
}, i can see in firebug that your style.css is conflicting. Remember to back up that style.css just in case!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5047/discussion-between-wayners247-and-graeme-leighfield)